# CSS background-clip property not being applied in React when background is dinamically changing

Tags: css, reactjs, background

If you want to jump into live code i prepared this CodeSandBox here: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/0j99m3m50

Here's what I am doing:

I have React component with state object having two properties (users, gradient) with values

```
this.state = {
    users: "programmer",
    gradient: "linear-gradient(120deg, #f093fb 0%, #f5576c 100%)"
};
```

And I am rendering user on an h1 JSX tag, but I should see the text clipped to each random gradient background, however it is not working, why?

```
render() {
  const gradually = this.state.gradient;
  const userGradient = {
    background: `${gradually}`,
    WebkitBackgroundClip: "text !important",
    backgroundClip: "text !important",
    color: "transparent"
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 style={userGradient} className="text">
        {this.state.users}
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a unique `key` on your `h1` tag to force a repaint. The key could be the same value as your `gradually` var. You can also get rid of the `!important` on your clips.

Here's a link to working changes to your sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/css-background-clip-not-being-applied-n34o0

```js
const gradually = this.state.gradient;
const userGradient = {
  background: `${gradually}`,
  WebkitBackgroundClip: "text", // Removed !important
  backgroundClip: "text", // Removed !important
  color: "transparent"
};

return (
  <div>
    <h1
      style={userGradient}
      className="text"
      key={gradually} // Add key
      >
      {this.state.users}
    </h1>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: For anyone coming to the thread from pure CSS/React:
putting just `backgroundClip: 'text'` will not work, you have to use `WebkitBackgroundClip:'text'`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in JavaScript and/or React. The problem is in style.

```
const userGradient = {
    background: `${gradually}`,
    WebkitBackgroundClip: "text !important",
    backgroundClip: "text !important",
    color: "transparent"   // <------------------ HERE
};
```

You have set your color to "transparent" so you can't see it cause it is errrrr fully transparent. But it is here. You can find it in your live example (right click, inspect element). So just remove it. Or change it to whatever you want. For example "#f00".

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color